# relations between classes

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm having a difficults to add rows to a table that located in different class.

Following are the classes structure:

[image]
**The dashed arrow is the desired relation that I dont manage to have**

in the `AddPanel` class I have a fileds and Addbutton.

when clicking the addButton I first creating an instance of Product (class located in Logic Package). Then I need to add row to the table (Using the `TableModel.AddRow` method).

Following are the GUI Looks (the focused tab is `AddPannel`):

[image]

I tried different approches but non of them were successed.

My last attempt was to create in the `Table` class the following method:

```
public void AddRow(Product p) {
    tbmStock.addRow(new Object[] { p.getExternalId(), p.getName(),
            p.getAmount(), p.getPriceForMe(), p.getPriceForCustomer() });
}
```

In addition, in the `AddPanel` class I tried to add the following method:

```
private void AddButtonAction() {
    btnAddProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                Product p = new Product(txtName.getText(), txtExternalID
                        .getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtAmount.getText()),
                        Double.parseDouble(txtPriceForMe.getText()),
                        Double.parseDouble(txtPriceForCustomer.getText()),
                        Integer.parseInt(txtFromYear.getText()), Integer
                                .parseInt(txtToYear.getText()), Integer
                                .parseInt(txtSupplier.getText()), Integer
                                .parseInt(txtCarType.getText()));
                AddRow(p); //This call doesn't compiles 
            }
            catch (Exception e1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
            }       
        }
    });

}
```

Any suggestions ? (actually I'm not sure even that my structure is good :S  )

Comment: You could simply add a reference of the table model to the AddPanel

Comment: actually "This doesn't work" means that it doesn't compiling due to the following :`The method AddRow(Product) is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}`

Comment: @Gil Peretz in this case MadProgrammer is mostly correct, you need a reference to your table in `AddPanel` and then call `table.AddRow()` in your `ActionListener`. Still I'd recommend creating a custom `TableModel` which is able to handle a collection of `Product`.

Answer (score 3):

Provide a custom event and event listener. If you create a new product fire the event and notify all listeners. The MainPanel (assuming that's where you create the instance of AddPanel), should register a listener. In this listener you then can update the table as the MainPanel has access to the table.

This is also known as the Mediator pattern.

**Some pointers:**

Create an event class, e.g. `ProductCreatedEvent extends EventObject`. Pass the Product as an argument to the constructor and make it accessible with a getter.

Create an event listener class: `interface ProductCreatedEventListener extends EventListener`. Provide a method such as `productCreated(ProductCreatedEvent productCreatedEvent)`.

In the AddPanel add something like:

```
private final List<ProductCreatedEventListener> productCreatedEventListeners = new ArrayList<>();
...

public void addProductCreatedEventListener(ProductCreatedEventListener productCreatedEventListener){
    productCreatedEventListeners.add(productCreatedEventListener);
}

public void removeProductCreatedEventListener(ProductCreatedEventListener productCreatedEventListener){
    productCreatedEventListeners.remove(productCreatedEventListener);
}

private void fireProductCreatedEvent(ProductCreatedEvent event){
    for (ProductCreatedEventListener productCreatedEventListener : productCreatedEventListeners){
        productCreatedEventListener.productCreated(event);
    }
}
```

Replace:

```
AddRow(p); //This isn't working
```

with

```
   fireProductCreatedEvent(new ProductCreatedEvent(AddPanel.this, p));
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm lack of expiriance in Java, can you give me an example or enhancment of the solution ?

Comment: I've added some pointers to my answers. Try it out and ask again if you have specific questions.